# Flutter Release Build Crashing on Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, proguard

I am facing a strange issue that my release build is crashing all of a sudden when it gets installed. The exception is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: firebase-iid-executor
 Process: com.my.app, PID: 9100
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toInstant()Lorg/threeten/bp/Instant; in class Ljava/util/Date; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.Date' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.HeartBeatInfoStorage.getFormattedDate(:148)
        at com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.HeartBeatInfoStorage.isSameDateUtc(:226)
        at com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.HeartBeatInfoStorage.shouldSendSdkHeartBeat(:236)
        at com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.HeartBeatInfoStorage.shouldSendGlobalHeartBeat(:252)
        at com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.DefaultHeartBeatController.getHeartBeatCode(:165)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(:19)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.startRpc(:1)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.getToken(:1)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$2$FirebaseInstanceId(:1)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$3.start(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(:7)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$3$FirebaseInstanceId(:5)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$0.then(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zze.run(:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

being a newbie in Flutter, I am unable to understand this crash. Can somebody please identify the problem what I am doing wrong and what can be the cause of this crash!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you using org.threeten.bp and is this really related to flutter or just android java?

Comment: my project is in Flutter and I am creating a release build which is crashing!

and I am not using "org.threeten.bp"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was using an older version of [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and what causes the issue of this crash was that the older version was skipping these files!

My Older version was **9.4.1** and I upgraded to **13.0.0** and that's it!

Actually I was playing with some proguard and dexguard rules. So this package was causing the crash because of older version of the package.

Cheers